# how to get the index of selected element in react native array

Tags: arrays, react-native

I want an index of the selected element in the react native array. I tried with indexOf() but it always returns -1. `School` is my array & `email` contains the value of the element whose index to find.

```
deleteDetails = (email) => {
  var index = School.indexOf(email);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the content of your `School` array?

Comment: @PrasunPal School array contains of email ids

Comment: Can you please share the output of `console.log(School)` value, I just wanted to know whether it is string or object.

Comment: 0: {email: "test1@test.com", remarks: "tt", slno: 1}
    1: {email: "test2@test.com", remarks: "ttt", slno: 2}
    2: {email: "test3@test.com", remarks: "tttt", slno: 3}
    3: {email: "test4@test.com", remarks: "4", slno: 4}
     success: "true" length: 4 proto: Array(0)

Answer (score 17):

As per your comment, `School` is an array of object, hence you need to use `findIndex` instead of `indexOf`

```js
var arr = [{
  email: "test1@test.com",
  remarks: "tt",
  slno: 1
}, {
  email: "test2@test.com",
  remarks: "ttt",
  slno: 2
}, {
  email: "test3@test.com",
  remarks: "tttt",
  slno: 3
}, {
  email: "test4@test.com",
  remarks: "4",
  slno: 4
}];

function getIndex(email) {
  return arr.findIndex(obj => obj.email === email);
}

console.log(getIndex("test4@test.com"));
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

const isLargeNumber = (element) => element > 13;

console.log(array1.findIndex(isLargeNumber));

This link was helpful
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

According to documentation, indexOf returns -1 only when value is not found in array.
Check your School array and email value before calling indexOf. You can use debugger or just simply add console.log before calling indexOf.

```
deleteDetails = (email) => {
  console.log(email);
  console.log(School);
  var index = School.indexOf(email);
}
```

If your email element is string "abc@email.com", your array should contain string elements.

```
var email = "abc@email.com";
var emails = ["abc@email.com", "def@email.com"];
console.log(emails.indexOf(email));
// expected output: 0
```

Edit: Considering comments below, your callback method should return the index of the element. So deleteDetails function should be like this.

```
deleteDetails(email, index) {
      // code
    }
```

Let's consider Flatlist for listing.

```
<FlatList
        data={this.props.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />

_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
<MyListItem
  id={item.id}
  onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
  selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item.id)}
  title={item.title}
  onDeleteButtonPressed={(item, index) => this.deleteDetails(item,index)}
/>
);
```

And you must create an onDeleteButtonPressed prop and call it when button pressed in  component to trigger deleteDetails function.

Comment: still returns -1, i tried with following
            var email1 = email;
            console.log(School);
            var emails = School;
            console.log(emails.indexOf(email1));




and console result is:

      0: {email: "test1@test.com", remarks: "tt", slno: 1}
      1: {email: "test2@test.com", remarks: "ttt", slno: 2}
      2: {email: "test3@test.com", remarks: "tttt", slno: 3}
      3: {email: "test4@test.com", remarks: "4", slno: 4}
success: "true"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)

 -1

Comment: If i'm reading this right, your school array is containing objects, not just string or numbers. Can you write your console.log(email) output?

Comment: actually it is displayed as a list with a remove icon, when i click to remove second email  the console.log(email) output is test2@test.com

Comment: your array contains objects but you are trying to find string inside and object array. You can't find. I'm writing a potential answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Flatlist then;

```
renderDataItem = ({item, index}) => {
return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress = {() => Actions.testing2({ sayi : index })}>
    <View style = {styles.allCointer}>
      <View style = {styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.textContainerTitle}> {item.Title} </Text>
        <Text style={styles.textContainerText}> {item.Description} </Text>
      </View>
      <Image
        style = {styles.image}
        source = {{uri : item.Files[0].FileUrl}}
      />
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)}
```

**index** parameter in that line,

```
renderDataItem = ({item, index}) => {
```

is your current index value.